# browser-sync gulp config

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, mamp-pro

I am trying to improve my Gulp configuration to include browser sync. I currently use MAMP Pro using `local.domain.com` for each site I'm working on (WordPress sites).

I'd like to get `browser-sync` to work using this current setup (watches my SASS files and minifies CSS when using watch).

I cannot seem to work out how to get browser sync to work with using the domain in my MAMP Pro setup.

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('lib/themes/domain/styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('lib/themes/domain/'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});





gulp.task('uglify', function () {
  gulp.src('lib/themes/domain/style.css')
    .pipe(uglifycss({
      "max-line-len": 80
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib/themes/domain/'));
});




// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'uglify']);
    gulp.watch('lib/themes/domain/styles/*/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('lib/themes/domain/styles/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('lib/themes/domain/style.css', ['uglify']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'uglify', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wont write the code for you, instead I'll show you how I like to do it. I run my browser-sync in a separate task, simply watch your build files for changes.

```js
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var urlPath = "your-url.com";

gulp.task('browser-sync', function (cb) {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: urlPath,
    }, function() {
        gulp.watch("Views/**/*.cshtml").on("change", browserSync.reload);
        gulp.watch('Assets/build/scripts/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
        gulp.watch('Assets/build/styles/**/*.css').on('change', function () {
            gulp.src('Assets/build/styles/**/*.css')
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
        });  
        cb();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll experiment with this over the next half hour and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Thank you for your help - it seems to work great for me! I had to tweak it ever so slightly to get it to look for sass changes, minify and then reload the page but it *seems* to work correctly so far! THANKS! Is there a way to change the url from localhost:3000 to the actual local domain I am working on?

Comment: Also I don't seem to be able to get other local devices on the same network to see the site. is there a way to do this or am I missing something? * EDIT actually I worked it out I wasn't typing in the IP with the port number. THANK YOU!!! I have literally been toying with getting this working on and off for a number of weeks. I'd +1 your answer if I could but I haven't got enough rep yet.

Comment: But if you're able to advise on my other question about rewriting the domain so it's not localhost:3000 but the local.domain.dev that is the same as the WP Db that would be extremely handy

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I've only been working with the localhost urls, but according to this thread: 
https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/646

This might work:

open: 'external',
host: 'domain.dev',
proxy: "domain.dev",
port: 8080,

Comment: Thanks Alex, I came across that this morning. Shame there is no way to get rid of the port number but we can't have it all! Thanks again for your help. Not sure where I was going wrong to be honest